# iOS JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I have two kinds of json formats that are getting parsed.

The data that gives no issues and when i fetch using "orderListView" key, the array gets generated fine. Array count is 2 in this case.

```
{
    "orderListView": [
    {

        "status": "AC",
        "totalRecords": "5",

    },
    {

        "status": "SH",
        "totalRecords": "5",

        }
    ]  
}
```

There's a square bracket missing in the below data and this too gets parsed into two objects where as this should have been one object similar to the above json. How do i handle this issue?

```
{
"orderListView": {

    "status": "AC",
    "totalRecords": "1",
    }
}
```

EDIT : Tried solution

```
 if ([[appDelegate.orderListJson objectForKey:@"orderListView"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    orderMainArray = [appDelegate.orderListJson objectForKey:@"orderListView"];
 }

else
{
      NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[appDelegate.orderListJson objectForKey:@"orderListView"]];
    orderMainArray = [array copy];

}
```

Comment: who generate this JSON?

Comment: Why you want it in an array? You should get it in an dictionary.

Comment: it is one object and each cell in the table should be displayed with all the values in this 1 object... So i convert the dictionary into a mutable array and then load the data onto my tableview

Comment: and why your colleague don't send you an array in the second case?

Comment: Oh I think you should consult your fellow colleague and tell him that the value of key "orderListView" should always be an array[].

Comment: NSString *str = [[[YourArray valueforkey:@"orderListView"]]valueforkey:@"status"];

Comment: Its better to tell your colleague to maintain the consistency. "orderListView" should be always an array

Comment: You Got result string as @"AC"

Comment: using your appDelegate singleton to access global data is bad, and you should feel bad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like

Comment: why is it bad? could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't 'resolve' it, you deal with it or get the source JSON changed.

To deal with it, check the Class type of the object that you get back when you request `orderListView`. It will either be an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` so you can test with `isKindOfClass:` to decide what to do.

Comment: this is a good suggestion.. One i know whether its an array or nsdictionary.. how do i create an array by making all those key pair values a one object?

Comment: The key pairs will already be in one object - the dictionary. You create an array with `@[ theValueITested ]` or [NSArray arrayWithObject:]`

Comment: But this will not make all of it one object in an array... In the 1st case i have 2 objects in the array. In the 2nd case i want it to be one object in the array...

Comment: That is what it will do. If `valueForKey:@ orderListView"` gives you a dictionary and you add it to an array you have an array containing one object.

Comment: I have tried what you said and doesnt give me the expected result. Please check my code i have added and tell me if i have missed something

Comment: You won't get a mutable array - unless you are using a special parser. Check for `NSArray`.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[appDelegate.orderListJson objectForKey:@"orderListView"] class]));` - what does it log?

Comment: My bad.. i was trying handling this in a different method which was not called... Thanks.. Solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is @ your fellow colleague side.

json should maintain one standard.
either should populate into an array or to an object.
the above two cases json is coming two different way.

@ your end you can manage using exception handling but, it is risky.

Comment: Don't use exception handling for logical processing. This is very bad practice. Check the data and act accordingly.